# Why is the CLR Object type serializable?

Tags: .net, serialization, clr

I am surprised to find that the [Object class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.aspx) is decorated with the Serializable attribute. Although Object instances can be useful (for thread synchronization, for instance), they have no state that can be meaningfully stored or re-hydrated. What problems would have encountered if the CLR Object class had not been marked as serializeable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it was not serializable, no other type in .NET would be serializable given that all types derive eventually from `System.Object`.

Comment: Right, the base class is part of the object graph.